# How to add List of Objects in entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing a simple spring boot application in java. I want to add a List of objects to my entity model but every time I get an error. 
Could someone guide me how the code should look like?
Also I am using a JPA repository, PostgreSQL database and Swagger.

```
public class Candidate {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
@Column(name = "UUID", unique = true, length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
private Long uuid;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
//@ElementCollection
private List<CandidateSkills> skills; 
}
```

And CandidateSkills list:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CANDIDATE_TABLE_SKILLS")
public class CandidateSkills {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String skillName;

private int skillLevel;
}
```

**Error:**
hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.employee.api.models.CandidateSkills

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found solutions. It was very simply.
**In** 
CandidateSkills change @Entity for @Embeddable

**And**
In List:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(
        name="CANDIDATE_SKILLS_TABLE",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="UUID")
)
private List<CandidateSkills> skills;
```

Please visit:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need "Many To Many" relation, maybe "one to many" relation works for you.

Anyway if you want to add "Many To Many" relation, you need to add another table to reference both table, but Spring do it for you :) just wants to define name fo that table (in this example "inner_table")

You need to add @JoinTable annotation in entity field definition in Candidate class like this:

```
.....
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "inner_table",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "candidateSkills_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<CandidateSkills> skills; 
....
```

and define reference back in CandidateSkills class like this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "skills")
private List<Candidate> Candidates;
```

Comment: First I thinked it worked but I checked it and unfortunately it doesn't. My code on below create a Candidate and Candidate SkillList but when I use JPArepository to get a Candidate a got a empty Skill list.